# Vim bindings for jupyter notebook/lab like Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Is there some way to have vim bindings in jupyter notebook/lab like in colab. In the included vim bindings for jupyter Lab, there isn't a NORMAL mode for editing inside the cell block. Colab however has better bindings as it allows use inside the cell block.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following process successfully (with Conda, Ubuntu 20.04).

In terminal:

```
conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

jupyter contrib nbextension install --user

conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

jupyter contrib nbextension install --user

jupyter --data-dir

cd /home/<USER>/.local/share/jupyter/nbextensions

git clone https://github.com/lambdalisue/jupyter-vim-binding vim_binding

jupyter nbextension enable vim_binding/vim_binding

jupyter notebook
```