# Exit insert mode in Google Colab

Tags: vim, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to exit the insert mode in Google Colab? Usual `Esc` doesn't work.

Even jumping out of the code block and jumping back in still activates in `Insert` mode.

Comment: That's odd, for me, the `<ESC>` key works just fine..

Comment: Did you select Vim keybindings from Tools > Settings > Editor?

Comment: I've had this issue on many different computers and browsers for as long as I remember @Zorzi. 

Yeah, if I hadn't, I wouldn't have been able to use vim keybindings in the first place to not be able escape `Insert` mode. @filbranden

Comment: Make sure that your editor is VI and not the default editor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you have any browser extensions which might be overriding the default behaviour of your keys? I had the same issue as you, with `esc` and `v` both failing to act as expected; but since disabling the [Vimium](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimium-ff/) extension, I've had no trouble with exiting `Insert` mode.

UPDATE: You can disable Vimium for specific sites. Just set an exclude URL filter for `https://colab.research.google.com/*` in the preferences for Vimium. The exact steps for modifying an extension's settings depend on your browser so I suggest Googling it.

Comment: It seems that others have had similar issues with Vimium. (e.g. 3rd comment in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59746583/8773953)).

Answer (score 0):

with `ctrl` + `c`, I could exit the insert mode.